# Javascript to find closest h2 from another element

Tags: javascript, closest

I am trying to find the closest **h2** tag from another element but am not able to by using **closest()**, as it returns error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at window.onload**.

```js
var strongTag = document.querySelectorAll('strong');
for (var i = 0, len = strongTag.length; i < len; ++i) {
 if(strongTag[i].innerHTML.indexOf('DoFindMe') !== -1) {
 strongTag[i].closest('h2').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
 }
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>

<div>
<h2>Head...<a>DoNotChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
</div>

<div>
<div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoNotFindMe</strong></div>
</div>

</div>

<div>

<div>
<h2>Head...<a>DoChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
</div>

<div>
<div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoFindMe</strong></div>
</div>

</div>

<div>
<h2>Head...<a>DoNotChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
</div>

<div>
<div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoNotFindMe</strong></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Well some of your `<strong>` elements don't have a closest parent `<h2>` (which is what `.closest()` looks for)

Comment: By *some*, Pointy means *none*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this alternative approach: Use `querySelectorAll` to locate all `h2` and `strong` elements. Then iterate through the catch, and on each `strong` element that matches the criteria, apply the desired style changes to the previous `h2` element in the list. This is possible because `querySelectorAll` is guaranteed to preserve the order of the elements as they appear in the document as per sec. **6.2 Finding Elements** of the [Selectors API](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/).

```
let i, h2, elems

elems = document.querySelectorAll('h2, strong')

for (i =0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].localName === 'h2')
        h2 = elems[i]
    else if (elems[i].innerHTML.indexOf('DoFindMe') !== -1)
        h2.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation, it worked great!

Answer (score 1):

None of your `strong` elements are inside an `h2` element, so *closest()* would only return nulls.

One option is to give a class to your container element and look for it, then search the `h2` element inside it.  Below, I've given the container element a `class="section"`:

```js
var strongTag = document.querySelectorAll('strong');
strongTag.forEach(tag => {
  const h2 = tag.closest('.section').querySelector('h2');
  if (h2)
    h2.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">

  <div>
    <h2>Head...<a>DoNotChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoNotFindMe</strong></div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="section">

  <div>
    <h2>Head...<a>DoChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoFindMe</strong></div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="section">
  <h2>Head...<a>DoNotChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoNotFindMe</strong></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense now that you mention it. The heading element would need to contain the strong that I am looking from. I first thought that since both the heading and parent div was contained within the same div I could use closest() to find the heading element as a sibling to the parent div of the strong element or as the child of both heading and strong elements parent div.

Answer (score 0):

The `.closest('h2')` return null because in your divs dont have any h2.

Add check null before using `if (strongTag[i].closest('h2') != null){ }`

Try add h2 to div it work

```
<div><h2><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoFindMe</strong></h2></div>
```

```js
var strongTag = document.querySelectorAll('strong');
for (var i = 0, len = strongTag.length; i < len; ++i) {
 if(strongTag[i].innerHTML.indexOf('DoFindMe') !== -1) {
 strongTag[i].closest('h2').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
 }
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>

<div>
<h2>Head...<a>DoNotChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
</div>

<div>
<div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoNotFindMe</strong></div>
</div>

</div>

<div>

<div>
<h2>Head...<a>DoChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
</div>

<div>
<div><h2><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoFindMe</strong></h2></div>
</div>

</div>

<div>
<h2>Head...<a>DoNotChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
</div>

<div>
<div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoNotFindMe</strong></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find closest only searches parents.  So it would work in a scenario like below:

```js
var strongTag = document.querySelectorAll('strong');
for (var i = 0, len = strongTag.length; i < len; ++i) {
 if(strongTag[i].innerHTML.indexOf('DoFindMe') !== -1) {
 strongTag[i].closest('h2').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
 }
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>

<div>
<h2>Head...<a>DoNotChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
</div>

<div>
<div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoNotFindMe</strong></div>
</div>

</div>

<div>

<div>
<h2>Head...<a>DoChangeMe</a>...ing
<div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoFindMe</strong></div>
</h2>
</div>

<div>
<div><h2><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoFindMe</strong></h2></div>
</div>

</div>

<div>
<h2>Head...<a>DoNotChangeMe</a>...ing</h2>
</div>

<div>
<div><a>DoNotChangeMe</a><strong>DoNotFindMe</strong></div>
</div>

</div>
```